# Synchronizing Outlook contacts and calendar with other Outlooks, Thunderbirds and Android

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, android, contacts

I would like to know if there is a way **other than using Google's services** to synchronize a desktop Outlook with a laptop running either Outlook/Windows or Thunderbird/Linux and an Android phone.

A good solution is to use Microsoft Exchange, running your own instance on a home server (that could be power consuming) or on cloud (like Azure).

However, since I do already have a Linux Azure server, I wonder if it's possible to run something equivalent. I don't need mail synchronization because I do already use IMAP. Contacts are most important and calendar is quite useful.

The setup should not be thought for business environment. For now I'm the only individual requiring to share data across devices. Later, I could share the service with others, each having his/her individual contacts/calendar database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Local Sync](http://www.psencik.cz/local-sync) for Android being a trade-off for Outlook synchronization. It allows me to synchronize several Outlook instances with a single Android phone. One of these Outlooks can be the "master" Outlook with proper overwriting settings on device.

Local Sync **doesn't** synchronize with Thunderbird and requires manual sync. Better than nothing